# Consider using IDbContextFactory to override the initialization of the DbContext at design-time

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, asp.net-identity-3

On an ASP.NET Core 1.0.1 project, using Entity Framework Core and ASP.NET Identity, I have the following context:

```
public class Context : IdentityDbContext<User, Role, Int32, UserClaim, UserRole, UserLogin, RoleClaim, UserToken> { 
  public Context(DbContextOptions options) : base(options) { }
  protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder) {
   base.OnModelCreating(builder);
  }
}
```

And the following entities:

```
public class User : IdentityUser<Int32, UserClaim, UserRole, UserLogin> { }
public class Role : IdentityRole<Int32, UserRole, RoleClaim> { }
public class RoleClaim : IdentityRoleClaim<Int32> { }
public class UserClaim : IdentityUserClaim<Int32> { }
public class UserLogin : IdentityUserLogin<Int32> { }
public class UserRole : IdentityUserRole<Int32> { }
public class UserToken : IdentityUserToken<Int32> { }
```

On Startup I have the following:

```
services.AddDbContext<Context>(x => x.UseSqlServer(connectionString, y => y.MigrationsHistoryTable("__Migrations")));

services
  .AddIdentity<User, Role>()
  .AddEntityFrameworkStores<Context, Int32>()
  .AddDefaultTokenProviders();
```

When I run `dotnet ef migrations add "FirstMigration"` I get the following error:

> An error occurred while calling method 'ConfigureServices' on startup
>   class 'WebProject.Startup'.  Consider using IDbContextFactory to
>   override the initialization of the DbContext at design-time.  Error:
>   GenericArguments[0], 'WebProject.User', on
>   'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore.UserStore`4[TUser,TRole,TContext,TKey]'
>   violates the constraint of type 'TUser'.

How to solve this problem?

Comment: Are you going to write any custom code inside RoleClaim, UserClaim, UserLogin, UserRole, UserToken? If not you can simply inherit from `Context  : IdentityDbContext<User, Role, Int32>`,  `User : IdentityUser<Int32>` and `Role : IdentityRole<Int32>`

Comment: @tmg I might need to write some custom code in those ... That is why I am using it this way. And MSFT added that option in https://github.com/aspnet/Identity/blob/dev/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore/IdentityDbContext.cs#L84 I am just now sure why I am having this problem as it seems everything is fine

Comment: I am not sure where the error comes from and why I get the suggestion 'Consider using IDbContextFactory'

Comment: Facing the same problem, just share my thoughts and still investigating... sounds like DI/Generics issue. perhaps what we need is a custom UserStore!

Comment: try dotnet ef migrations add "FirstMigration" --verbose
 It will give you the full stacktrace, potentially identifying the source of the error

Answer (score 5):

I apologise for posting a partial answer but it will be usefull for many...

> An error occurred while calling method 'ConfigureServices' on startup class

Your method `Startup.ConfigureServices(...)` is being called and it is throwing an exception. The exception probably happens because when running `dotnet ef` the application entry point is not `Program.Main()` as usual.

Try

```
    dotnet ef migrations add "FirstMigration" --verbose
```

That will print the error message and you will be able to better understand the issue.

Comment: Learning Program.Main() was not entry point along with dotnet ef migrations add "FirstMigration" --verbose helped me solve this.